Calibration/Filtering Order
Let's suppose we have a stream of data from a 3-axis sensor like a MEMS magnetometer. Each of the sensor's axes have an output bias, gain, and misalignment (all axes should be orthogonal). Additionally, there is additive white Gaussian noise on each sensor axis.
The question is: What is the order of calibration and filtering to most accurately recover the "true" sensor values? Would it be the following:?

Account for axes non-orthogonality and gain with a calibration matrix
Subtract biases from each axis
Filter out the AWGN

Or should filtering happen first?
